# var obj = window.open("", "parentwindow", "") opens blank page in IE11 instead of giving existing "parentwindow" reference

Tags: object, reference, window, internet-explorer-11

My application was working fine in IE 9 & 10. As soon as production desktops migrated to IE11 we have seen many issues like model windows are not closing and when we click on any hyperlink blank pages are popping up.

When I investigate I understand that in IE11 we are not getting the reference of already opened window for below code.

```
var obj = window.open("", "parentwindow", "");
```

Can anybody tell me why this issue is happening and let me know is there any alternate solution to get the existing window reference?

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone has suggestion on this issue?